# return json attribute name from file using c#

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I'm attempting to setup an azure function that pulls a message from the azure service bus and captures the message structure.  In this case the message structure can be different per message so I need to dynamically read the structure of the message.  I can pull back the message and deserialize it into a dynamic array.  My code seams to see the attribute : value item but I cant seem to get it to read the attribute name.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FReadJson
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("catread", "ReadFile", Connection = "testconn")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
            dynamic jsonarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(mySbMsg);
                      
            foreach (var item in jsonarray)
            {
                var str = item;
                Console.WriteLine(item.key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lets say the first message sent is

```
{
  "type": "input",
  "correlationId": "9e43344c-f787-4758-ad66-374c2492a6ac",
  "sequence": "1",
  "utc": "11/2/2020 1:36:41 PM",
}
```

and the second message sent is

```
{
  "type": "output",
  "childPath": "",
  "processVersion": "",
  "utc": "11/2/2020 1:36:41 PM",
}
```

Comment: show us the data that would be passed in to your function stored in `mySbMsg`

Comment: @Andy - as stated the messages are variable. so lets say {
  "type": "input",
  "correlationId": "9e43344c-f787-4758-ad66-374c2492a6ac",
  "sequence": "1",
  "utc": "11/2/2020 1:36:41 PM",
}

Comment: And the next message would be. {
  "type": "output",
  "childPath": "",
  "processVersion": "",
  "utc": "11/2/2020 1:36:41 PM",
}

Comment: Is `type` the same each time? And I don't think you mean "attribute", you mean key and value.

Comment: @Andy Yes key and value.  Thanks.  And no  Type is not the same each time I can get a completely variable set of key names.

Comment: OK, try this: `var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(mySbMsg);` Then iterate over the dictionary.

Comment: which assembly reference is IDictionary coming from?

Comment: add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: sorry I'm new at this (obviously) so added the dictionary line, changed my for each to be var item in dictionary attempted to writeline item.key and I'm getting an error saying its inaccessable due to its protection level

Comment: nevermind.  case typo.  found it

Comment: And that was the fix write it up so I can mark it and give you credit.  and Thank you.

Comment: OK Done -- glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not know the key/value pairs coming in to your function, you could deserialize to `Dictionary`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// ...

var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(mySbMsg);
                  
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
}
```